# Angular 5: Cannot fnd "SocketIOClient"

Tags: angular, socket.io

I am trying to implement `socket.io` in my angular project but it fails to resolve the namespace for `SocketIOClient` when compiling the code.

I have installed `@types/socket.io-client` so the angular app would know the types of `societ.io` client, i don't know why it fails to resolve them when i have the `package.json` like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/socket.io": "^1.4.36",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.32",
    ....
}
```

This started happening when i created this code:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
    socket: SocketIOClient;
}
```

I was planning to make a service to handle all socket actions needed for the app, how can i fix this?

Comment: did you imported the socket.io in angular?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the socket io from nodemodules

```
import * as SocketIOClient from 'socket.io-client';

import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
    socket: SocketIOClient;
}
```